# Unparseable date exception in Android 2.3.3 not present in newer versions

Tags: java, android, date

I am parsing a date string using the following SimpleDateFormat:

Code Snippet:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("'cappicor' yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm zz", Locale.US);
dateTime = format.parse(title)
```

Here is an example "title" date String I receive:

```
"cappicor 2013-12-07 11:54 UTC"
```

This works fine in many newer devices and versions of Android, but fails in android 2.3.3 with:

**java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "cappicor 2013-12-07 11:54 UTC"**

I have browsed many SO answers, related to the Locale used, and even parsing out possible control characters from the String - with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would get rid of this cappicor prefix and then try parsing.

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace? Maybe there is a bug in there. E.g. that particular Android version does not know that "UTC" is a timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the Java versions from 1.4 to 1.7 gave me that error, though in fact Android 2.3.3 did.

From the ORACLE documentation:

> *Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation. "''" represents a single quote*

From the Android documentation:

> *'' single quote (Literal) 'o''clock':o'clock*

So there is no difference here. However, I noticed that the time zone `UTC` caused an issue. After changing the code to ...

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date dateTime = format.parse("2013-12-07 11:54");
```

... it works. Slightly strange because ...

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm zz", Locale.US);
Date dateTime = format.parse("2013-12-07 11:54 GMT");
```

... works pretty fine as well (same for EST, PST) and `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` returns `UTC`, `CET` and `MET` which all do not work.

Conclusion: use ...

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("'cappicor' yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date dateTime = format.parse("cappicor 2013-12-07 11:54");
```

... as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it alright. I assume it's a bug that was fixed in later versions.